# How do you prove that the complex inverse is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, topological-groups

I tried to show that the continuous at a point $\delta / \epsilon$ definition holds but failed.  Now I'm thinking along the lines of multiplicative group: $C \rightarrow C, x \mapsto bx$ has  inverse $x \mapsto b^{-1} x$ composing the maps is analogous to multiplication in $C$ and $\phi : C \times C \rightarrow C, (x,y) \mapsto xy $ is continuous so it's partial functions are continuous, then... and I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you mean multiplicative inverse?

Comment: Yeah, why?  Additive inverse is easy to do.

Comment: You write $C\to C$. You do this by the inverse function theorem, if that makes you happy :) Or, you could just note that punctured discs $D_r(0)$ are a  base for $\mathbb{C}^\times$. What is the preimage of this set? What things inverses have modulus less than $r$?

Comment: How do those form a base - wouldn't you need disks all over the place?  That rhymed.

Comment: I think I got it now.  Conjugation transfers disks to disks.  And the inverse is $z^* / |z|^2$ so somehow composing the maps makes this bad boy continuous.

Comment: Yeah, that was crazy, but you just have to translate those discs, and the preimage is equally easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \neq 0$ be a complex number.
We will prove that the map $f\colon \mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ defined by $f(x) = x^{-1}$ is continuous at $a$, where $\mathbb{C}^*$ denotes the multiplicatve group of $\mathbb{C}$.

We get $|f(x) - f(a)| = |x - a|/|x||a|$.

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be a positive number.
Let $\delta =$ min$\{|a|/2, \epsilon |a|^2/2\}$.
Suppose $|x - a| \lt \delta$.
Since $|a| = |x - a - x| \le |x - a| + |x|$,
$|a| - |x| \le |x - a| \lt \delta$
Hence
$|a| - \delta \lt |x|$
Hence
$|f(x) - f(a)| = |x - a|/|x||a| \lt \delta/(|a| - \delta)|a| \le 2\delta/|a|^2 \le \epsilon$.
Hence $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Compositions of continuous maps are continuous including compositions of the form $f(h(x), g(x))$.  Conjugation is easily shown to be continuous and also the magnitude function $|x|$.  And in $\mathbb{R}$ $1/f(x)$ is continuous at all $f(x) \neq 0$, since inverse is not defined at $0$ we don't need to worry.  Since the inverse of a complex number $z$ equals $z^* / |z|^2$ and it's a composition of the continuous maps above it's also continuous!!!! :)

We should note that we transfered the common range of some of the above functions to $\mathbb{C}$ to make it work, that should be okay as the preimage $g^{-1}(U)$ for $U$ open in $\mathbb{C}$ is then $g^{-1}(U \cap \mathbb{R})$ for instance and $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$.